# Sketch app: Is it possible to delete part of border of shape?

Tags: sketch-app

This is trivial in Illustrator but I can't figure out if it's possible in Sketch app. In Illustrator you would just select part of a path between 2 anchors and delete it.

Answer (score 23):

select the shape you want to edit. Go to Layer->Paths->Scissors. Click on the path you want to delete. This deletes path between two anchor points. You can add anchor points by double-clicking on the object.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend this, but if you're still looking to keep the shape as is instead of using the `Scissors` tool you can add a Shadow to it.

[Shadow Hack on SketchTalk](https://sketchtalk.io/discussion/1098/possible-a-border-only-on-one-side-of-a-shape)

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend open path option if the shape your deleting is a oval Layer->Path->Open path